# How to fetch userId/username with the help of Phone no in Graph Api (Facebook)?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I have gone through the following link of Facebook Graph API:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api

But I am unable to find the API which Provides the userid/username by inputting mobile number.

My Objective:

Is there any Graph API which will find user ID/ username/profile link from a phone number?

Comment: for calling graph Api, need AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(). and you will find out current access token only if you are login with FB. other wise it will give you null. so login with fb first, either by phone number or email id.

Comment: I am logged in and using Facebook Graph explorer to fetch the user data

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Comment: see my answer there below

Answer (score 0):

may be you can try this to get user data:

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {


                            Debug.trace("resultObject", object.toString());


                            String firstName = object.optString("first_name");
                            String lastName = object.optString("last_name");
                            String email = object.optString("email");
                            String socialMediaUserId = object.optString("id");
                            String birthday = object.optString("birthday ");
                        }
                    }
            );
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString(FIELDS, FB_REQUEST_PARAMETER);
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
```

where

```
private final String FIELDS = "fields";
    private final String FB_REQUEST_PARAMETER = "id, first_name, last_name, email,gender, birthday, location";
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but this is not what I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the username or the direct profile link, not even by authorizing a user. You can only get an "App Scoped ID" by authorizing the user, and his real name. There is no way to search by phone number either, you cannot even get the phone number of a user by authorizing him.

Comment: After a spending no of hours, I can say you are right, no way to find user id/ username with the mobile no